# Is there a way to generate a lognormal distribution from a pre-defined normal distribution?

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, logarithm

I have the code which generates a normal distribution as a pdf, centered at the mean 400, with st

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats

muPrev, sigmaPrev = 400, 40.
a = np.random.normal(muPrev, sigmaPrev, 100000)
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(a, 1000, density=True)
plt.plot(bins, 1/(sigmaPrev * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) *
           np.exp( - (bins - muPrev)**2 / (2 * sigmaPrev**2) ),linewidth=3, color='r')
```

[image]

and I can visualise it. But what if I wanted to convert this into a lognormal distribution? So that I now get values of mu and sigma that correspond to this as a log distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is posted by @SamMason is not correct. It is somewhat working because your mean and sd are relative large.

Ok, here is what would be correct way to get parameters of the [Log-Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

You have predefined values of mean (corresponding to your Gaussian mean) and sd (again, your Gaussian sd).

Mean=exp(μ+σ<sup>2</sup>/2)

Var =(exp(σ<sup>2</sup>) - 1)(exp(2μ+σ<sup>2</sup>))

Here μ and σ are log-normal (NOT gaussian) parameter. You have to find them.

1. Compute mean from your Gaussian mean (ok, that one is easy, they are equal)
2. Compute variance from your Gaussian sd (square)
3. Using formulas above solve two non-linear equations system and get your μ and σ
4. Plug μ and σ into your sampling routine and draw samples

UPDATE

Mean<sup>2</sup>=exp(2μ+σ<sup>2</sup>)

Var/Mean<sup>2</sup> = (exp(σ<sup>2</sup>) - 1)

So here is your σ. To be more elaborate

Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup> = exp(σ<sup>2</sup>) - 1

exp(σ<sup>2</sup>) = 1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>

σ<sup>2</sup> = ln(1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>)

From first equation now you could get μ

2μ+σ<sup>2</sup> = ln(Mean<sup>2</sup>)

2μ=ln(Mean<sup>2</sup>) - σ<sup>2</sup> = ln(Mean<sup>2</sup>) - ln(1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>) = ln((Mean<sup>2</sup>)/(1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>))

Please, check the math, but this is the way to get PRECISE log-normal μ,σ parameters to match desired Mean and Sd.

@SamMason approximation works, I believe, only if in the expression for

σ<sup>2</sup> = ln(1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>)

one have second term much larger than 1. THen you could drop 1 and have log of ratios.

UPDATE II

2μ=ln((Mean<sup>2</sup>)/(1 + Sd<sup>2</sup>/Mean<sup>2</sup>)) = ln(Mean<sup>4</sup>/(Mean<sup>2</sup> + Sd<sup>2</sup>))

μ=1/2 ln(Mean<sup>4</sup>/(Mean<sup>2</sup> + Sd<sup>2</sup>))=ln(Mean<sup>2</sup>/Sqrt(Mean<sup>2</sup> + Sd<sup>2</sup>))

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - are you meaning that to get my σ i must calculate Var = (exp(σ2) - 1)*Mean^2? and then square root that to get σ?

Comment: @Landon no, let me clarify a bit more. See update

Comment: thanks for elaborating that, out of curiosity, how does that mean estimation differ from the one here, for example? is it used in different scenarios? https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/23a768dbf96141bc3f1a194ce4d3ac002b40564e

Comment: @Landon looks like exactly the same expression. See another update in a sec

Answer (score 0):

You could directly generate samples for a lognormal distribution with https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.lognormal.html, alternatively:

```
log_norm = np.exp(a)
```

Note that if you want to generate the lognormal directly you need to calculate the appropriate mean and variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: What I meant was, from the distribution I have, how do I calculate the mean and var from the samples and mu/sigma values I already have?

Comment: Mu and sigma are the one you specified for the normal distribution, for the lognormal derived one just use the formula in the wiki page. For the mean and std of the sample use a.mean() and a.std()

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you mean. The formula I found here is for the pdf. How will that give me the lognormal mu and sigma?

Comment: So your question is, given the mean and std of a normal distribution, how to obtain the mean and std of the corresponding lognormal distribution?

Comment: yep, and i want to then visualise that like my plot. but i want to know how this can be implemented in python, not theoretically.

Comment: Mean of your distribution is `log(400)` and standard deviation is just `40 / 400`, so approx `6, 0.1`

Answer (score 0):

To give a more complete answer, here's some code that draws a figure with two plots: one shows your existing Gaussian draws and another for log-normal draws.  I keep the first and second moments the same (i.e. mean and variance) by setting the [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) mu=`log(mu)` and sigma=`sd/mu`.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sps
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sd = 400, 40
n = 100_000

# draw samples from distributions
a = np.random.normal(mu, sd, n)
b = np.random.lognormal(np.log(mu), sd / mu, n)

# use Scipy for analytical PDFs
d1 = sps.norm(mu, sd)
# warning: scipy parameterises its distributions very strangely
d2 = sps.lognorm(sd / mu, scale=mu)

# bins to use for histogram and x for PDFs
lo, hi = np.min([a, b]), np.max([a, b])
dx = (hi - lo) * 0.06
bins = np.linspace(lo, hi, 101)
x = np.linspace(lo - dx, hi + dx, 501)

# draw figure
fig, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(8, 5))

ax1.set_title("Normal draws")
ax1.set_xlim(lo - dx, hi + dx)
ax1.hist(a, bins, density=True, alpha=0.5)
ax1.plot(x, d1.pdf(x))
ax1.plot(x, d2.pdf(x), '--')

ax2.set_title("Log-Normal draws")
ax2.hist(b, bins, density=True, alpha=0.5, label="Binned density")
ax2.plot(x, d1.pdf(x), '--', label="Normal PDF")
ax2.plot(x, d2.pdf(x), label="Log-Normal PDF")

ax2.legend()
fig.supylabel("Density")
```

which produces the following output:

[image: matplotlib output]

Because the distributions are so close here, I've included  dashed lines to show the other distribution for easier comparison.  Note that the log-normal distribution will always be slightly right-skewed, more so as the variance increases.

Comment: So am I understanding this correctly, the lognormal distribution is merely the mu value taken for the normal distribution with a logarithm applied to it, but the sd value for this would be original sd/mu? The reason I ask is because I eventually want to use the values of mu and sigma for this lognormal distribution to create a likelihood function to then feed into and MCMC algorithm

Comment: yup, just look at the distribution's definition.  as noted by @Mattiatore it's just the exponential of a Gaussian, and the rest follows directly from that.  sounds a bit like you're doing Bayesian stats, if so, https://mc-stan.org/ might be easier than coding it up yourself

Comment: @Landon what is stated here is, of course, incorrect. Works only because mu is large

Comment: Posted correct answer

Comment: oops!  yup, not sure how I was thinking it was so simple.  See @SeverinPappadeux's answer for what you'd have to do in the general case (i.e. when `sd` isn't small when compared to `mu`)